# SignIn with oidc-client and identityServer4 in different domain

Tags: c#, vue.js, .net-core, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I have a VueJs application in localhost that use the `oidc-client.js` library to do the login to an `IdentityServer4` server in production, in another domain.

After login, the IdentityServer redirects me to the VueJs app, than I call the method `signinRedirectCallback()`, but the oidc-client method `getUser()` does not give to me the user information.

If I check the LocalStorage I can see the `oidc.user:IdentityServer4Url` value where I can see all the information of the user (access_token, id_token, profile ecc...), and I've the Cookies 'idsrv', 'idsrv.session', 'ARRAffinity'.

If I try the application in the same domain, it works. 
Is it possible to have a localhost app and do the login to another domain?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can.  Is the user info logged if you do `signinRedirectCallback().then(user => { console.log(user) });`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can absolutely have your Identity server in a different domain and pretty much most of the big IDP's (Identity Provider) will live in a different domain.

When you said, you have information on the local storage, did u make sure, the access token is the same as the one you have received in the singin response url? in the local storage you would see a property called "expires_at" I guess, see if that value is valid.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/UserManager.js#L595

If all things are right, I can't think of any other reason why it should not retrieve.

One other debug technique which could help you is? Go to your node_modules folder, look for oidc-cient-js folder, and modify the main property in package.json file from oidc-client.min.js to oidc-client.js, this way you can keep breakpoint and debug step by step and find out what is going on.

Hope this helps.